# Unit Testing Coverage RxJS.Observable.Catch Block

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs

I am attempting to get unit test coverage on a code block similar to the following, specifically the catch block that calls a method to handle errors:

```
return this._http.get(/someurl)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let results = <any>response.json();
                return results;
            })
            .catch(response => {
                return this.handleError(response);
            });
```

I have attempted this:

```
it('Should call base handleError method when an error occurs',
    fakeAsync(inject([MyService, MockBackend],
        (myService: MyService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
              mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
                  expect(connection.request.url).toEqual(
                      `/someurl`
                  );
                  connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                      status: 404
                  })));
              });

              spyOn(myService, 'handleError');
              myService.getData(1);
              tick();
              expect(myService.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
})));
```

The catch block is never called and the test fails as the spy was never hit.  I have tried using MockConnection.mockError with no luck there either.  I have seen posts that require using the subscribe error handler on the Observable, but there has to be a way to trigger the catch block via an error response too?  I have tried throwing an Observable failure via Observable.throw() but that didn't seem to get me down the right path either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the observable to make it perform the asynchronous operation.

```
spyOn(myService, 'handleError');
myService.getData(1); // subscribe here
tick();
expect(myService.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

should be implemented this way

```
spyOn(myService, 'handleError');
myService.getData(1).subscribe(value => {
  expect(myService.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();    
});
```

Comment: I had some other issues around some observable types not being returned where expected.  In addition, I will add I had to provide a subscribe(value => {}, error => { // expect here }). To resolve the issues I was experiencing with the expect statement.  The empty subscribe block seems silly to me, but the error block allowed me to do my assertions as desired.  Bottom line, non-error cases I had the subscribe block I don't know why I didn't think I needed that for a negative test too.  Thanks!